# Illegal string offset in third variable only

Tags: php, mysql, offset

I am having an extremely weird problem that does not make sense to me.

I am getting the "Illegal string offset" in my third variable that is part of the array in a foreach loop no matter what the data is pulling from. At first it thought it was an issue with my Date formatting but if I change it to another field it's the same error message only with that field name in place.

The code looks like this:

```
$posts = get_tableContents($con,'posts');
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    $postID = $post['id'];
    $post = $post['subject'];
    $mydate = "something to test";
    $datePosted = $post['date'];

    echo $mydate." <a class='community' href='displayNews.php?post=".$postID."'>".$post."</a>".$datePosted."<br />";
}
```

If I switch $datePosted with $post the same issue happens just changes the error to say subject instead of date.

Results:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'subject' in D:\xampp\htdocs\snj\news.php on line 26
something to test 2014-09-09

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Here is the function I am calling in case it is something in there:

```
function get_tableContents($con,$table)
{
    $results = array();
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $table")
        or die ("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {
        $results[] = $row;    
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Are You sure u have subject key in your array? `var_dump($posts);` before foreach and after get_tableContents();

Comment: You are re assigning $post in the loop.. Then try to use it like an array.. Call your variables something different t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment. In your loop you make $post equal to the post subject... And then try to pull out something else from post.

Aka `$post = $post['subject'];`
Change that to`$postSubject = $post['subject'];`

Also check the case.. You may need to do `$post['Subject']` in case the column name is a capital s on subject

Comment: ugggh! Silly me. It's been a long weekend and didn't catch that. Thanks so much John!

Comment: @jAC No problem!! Glad I could help. Thanks for the quick response and uovote. I'll reciprocate :)